# Force stop edit cell in JTable on mouse click

Tags: swing, jtable, mouseevent

How to force stop editing a cell in a JTable when the user clicks on any other component than the table itself?

Tried this but it didn't work...

```
myTable.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

... or this, which also does not work as expected

```
Component co = myTable.getEditorComponent(); 
if (co != null && !(co instanceof JComboBox)) { 
    co.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() { 
        public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) { 
            TableCellEditor tce = myTable.getCellEditor(); 
            if (tce != null) { 
                tce.stopCellEditing(); // should accept partial edit 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Having a button with an action listener attached to it makes it possible to force stop editing of any cell in the table, however that's not really the solution I am looking for. 
It should work by clicking on any component.

**SSCCE**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;

public class TableExample {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    final Object rowData[][] = { { "1", "one", "not empty" }, { "2", "two", "" }, { "3", "three", "" } };
    final String columnNames[] = { "#", "Some Column", "Some Other Column" };

    final JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

      public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
         System.out.println("column: "+e.getColumn());
         if(1==e.getColumn()){
             System.out.println(table.getModel().getValueAt(e.getLastRow(), e.getColumn()));
             String value = table.getModel().getValueAt(e.getLastRow(), e.getColumn()).toString();
             int rowIndex = e.getLastRow();

             if(table.getModel().getValueAt(e.getLastRow(), 2).toString().isEmpty())
                 table.getModel().setValueAt(value,e.getLastRow(), 2);
         }
      }
    });

    table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
    table.setValueAt("",0,0);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setSize(700, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

Comment: The `terminateEditOnFocusLost` property should work. Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `It should work by clicking on any component.` - there are no components in the frame that gain focus when you click on them. What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to save the data when the user clicks on the "Close" button? If so, then use a WindowListener and handle windowClosing() and stop editing on the table.

Comment: Actually, I just want cell editing to stop when user clicks somewhere outside the table.

Answer (score 0):

The table does not take up all the space in the viewport of the scrollpane so you are actually clicking on the viewport. By default a viewport doesn't gain focus when you click on it so there is no focusLost method generated on the table.

Maybe you can just use the following so the table fills the viewport:

```
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
```

Otherwise, you would need to add a MouseListener to the viewport to handle the mouse click event. You would need to do this for all components on the frame that cannot receive focus, like a JPanel.

Or, maybe another approach is to use an AWTEventListener to listen for all mouse clicks. The draw back to this approach is that you can't distinguish between a click on a focusable component and a non-focusable component so you would be attempting to stop the cell editing every time a click is made. See [Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) for more information.